# Visual C++: stop symbols from being exported

Tags: c++, windows, dll, visual-studio-2012

I'm working on a dll project and am using the following to clean up some of my exported symbol names:

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/EXPORT:Some_function=_Some_function@4")
```

where Some_function is defined as, say:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall Some_function(int);
```

Checking my dll, however, I'm seeing both Some_function and _Some_function@4 being exported. Is there any way that I can hide the decorated function name and export only the cleaned up name?

Comment: Remove `declspec(dllexport)`.

Comment: *Facepalm* Thanks. btw: I enjoy your blog.